# Developing webservice(json format) for android client using java compatible with appengine server

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, google-app-engine

I am developing a student android app which uses json webservice. i want to populate student news or events daily in my android application.i can bulid all my client side procedure.

but i am not able to build server side webservice.please give me some stemps to follow to build my webservice on server side.

my requirements:

i want a webform where i can enter student news and events and that should be stored on webservice(json).
this webservice must be comapatible with appengine.
please help me i strucked with that i con't move work..

sorry for my english.

advance thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 5):

App Engine has some very nice tutorials on their website, I'd recommend starting there:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating

I'd just create a simple form which you would POST to a servlet.  You don't necessarily have to send JSON data, it'd be easier to send App Engine standard POST or GET data, parse it, and do what you want with it.  If you want the android app to receive JSON data, I'd recommend looking into Jackson:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

This library will parse java objects and return them as JSON strings, quite nice.

Good luck!